# Can I write pipeline outputs to a local folder when using PortablePipeline with a docker container?

Tags: docker, apache-beam

I'm running an Apache Beam pipeline using a `PortableRunner` and a custom Docker image. The pipeline receives a commandline argument for an output folder. In the "prod" settings this is a bucket in GCS but in my "dev" settings I'd like this to be written to the local filesystem (obviously with much smaller input files, just for quick debugging and testing).

My pipeline runs and finishes successfully but the outputs are written to a local folder inside the container. I couldn't find a way to bind a local folder into the container.

Can I control mount flags for the beam workers containers? If not - what would be a possible solution?
I'd rather avoid writing to a bucket but can work around this if that's the only option...